# In Javascript, how to assign JSON data retrieved from an AJAX request to a global variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want assign to a global variable, JSON data retrieved from an AJAX request. Here is my code:

```
var ajaxData = "blabla";

$.ajax({
    url: "url.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        action: "searchResultsCallback",
        termId: 5
    },
    success: function(data) {
        ajaxData = data;
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
})

console.log(ajaxData);
```

Now, in the `$.ajax` function I changed `ajaxData` from `blabla` to whatever the value of `data` is. But, instead, in the console, the output I get is:

> blabla
>
> **XHR finished loading: GET** "*url.php?action=searchResultsCallback&termId=523*".

So it seems like the browser prints the value of `ajaxData` first, and then executing the ajax request. More than that. if I change the `success` option to be like this:

```
success: function(data) {
    ajaxData = data;
    console.log(ajaxData);
},
```

Then I DO get the data retrived from the ajax request!

> blabla
>
> **XHR finished loading: GET** "*url.php?action=searchResultsCallback&termId=523*".
>
> [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

Why is that? How can I fix it?

Comment: Thats how async code works. Dont try and fix it - just call the code that requires the data **after** the success function fires. Synchronous ajax is possible, but can hang the browser so is generally to be avoided

Comment: Could you please show me how? I am not quite sure I understand. Thank you very much!

Comment: Basically, put the code that uses `ajaxData` into a function, for example `function doStuff(){//code here}` then call that once the ajax completes `success:function(data){ajaxData = data; doStuff();}` By doing that you will also see that probably you dont need a global, and can instead just pass `data` as a parameter of the function. Understanding async and callbacks is a fundamental part of JavaScript and is too large a subject to discuss in comment here

Comment: But if, for example, I want data to be in a variable so I could use it multiplt times without calling the server everytime, how should I do this?

Comment: All code that requires `ajaxData` is contained within, or called from, `doStuff` function. As that function is not called until the data is populated, you are fine.